# load content with Jquery together with sending variable in to it

Tags: jquery

I have a variable `- x` in jquery, I am loading a php part in `div` block and I need sent that variable to it.

So -

```
$(document).on('click','#link',function () {
var x=5;
$("#block").load("file.php");
});
```

In result I am still in the same page.I just need to have `variable x` in it.

I think about to use GET method or XMLHttpRequest but I don't want  to another page, I just need to load a php part in block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to send data as second argument:

```
$(document).on('click', '#link', function() {
  $("#block").load("file.php", {
    x: 5
  }, function(res) {
    //your callback 
  });
});
```

**References**

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: +1 A much more elegant solution to use the `load` parameters rather than construct a URL string like I did.

Comment: Ooo that is interest variant

Comment: Glad that I helped you. Also thanks @Lix for the positive feedback.

Comment: just out of topic but in result I use $i= stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['x']));   in reault gave me .5.  Do you know how to erase the dots from both sides that i can use the variable as a number

Comment: `$_POST['x']` that seems php to me that I'm not good at. You can post another question related in php how to fix this issue.

Comment: thanks any way, will try to solve it by my self first, and if so will create a new ticket

Answer (score 4):

You could append a GET parameter to the URL you are loading and then within that file you can insert your variable in the appropriate place. There are no redirections, or naviagations to other pages, the variable will be passed as part of the request for the content.

```
var x=5;
$("#block").load("file.php?extra_parameter=" + x);
```

Your PHP file will then have access to the `x` variable via the [`$_GET` 'superglobal' variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
$x = $_GET["extra_parameter"];
```

Comment: @alex_mike - consider using the method in [Alex Char's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30567853/558021) answer, I feel it is much more readable and also will allow you to extend the number of variables very easily.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variable value via Get parameter like the following:

```
$("#block").load("file.php?variable_name=" + x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but I'm going to post it anyway:
Try out Jquery.ajax(), it will allow you to send your data as POST

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data, //The variables you want to send through
  complete: function(obj, status) {
      //Here you can take the response from the request and load
      //it into the current page
  },
  dataType: dataType //What you expect the format of the returned
                     //data will be, usually html or json
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If that seems like too much trouble, there's also a wrapper for all that:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Take a look at the [docs for the `.load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/), it is actually shorthand for the `.$.get` function. Furthermore, as detailed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30567853/558021), the `.load()` function also supports a `data` property that acts the in the same way as the `data` property in a call to `$.ajax`.

Comment: Yeah, there's a couple of wrappers available, but I think it's better to stick with the one closer to the core, as it gives a lot more extensibility. The wrappers are limited to certain very specific use conditions, for instance, the .load() function doesn't support defining a dataType. This might seem trivial, but I've seen it many times where I json_encode something sent through the backend, and the browser reads it as html for some reason.